# Why does Fedora have two `ptmx` files?

Tags: linux, fedora, devices, pty

I know that the file `/dev/ptmx` is used to generate a master file for a pseudo-terminal. But I have found out that Fedora has another `ptmx` file (`/dev/pts/ptmx`):

[image]

What is the purpose of this second file?

Comment: Assuming you understand the purpose of `/dev/ptmx`, try `mount | grep pts`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura `/dev/pts` is a separate filesystem, so what? I suspect that the answer does have to do with that, but in what way? (I think the answer is if you have multiple instances of /dev/pts`, for a machine with virtual environments that shouldn't see each others' terminals.)

Comment: @Gilles It's in RAM. Different views can be (and are) given to different processes. Pseudoterminals are requested at `/dev/ptmx`, which is the same for everybody, but they are allocated at `/dev/pts`, which is a "customized" view in RAM. `/dev/pts/ptmx` is there for the consistency of internal requests. All this improves security and saves space on disk (since, perhaps surprisingly, devices take a non-trivial amount of space on disk). And of course it's Linux-specific. Disclaimer: this is my recollection of what's going on. While I've used Linux since 0.99.x, I've never been a huge fan of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason, like with many things in the world of computing, is history and backwards compatibility.

Back in 2.4.* kernels, before `udev` (the current virtual filesystem solution for `/dev`) existed in Linux, there was two competing solutions, the "traditional Unix way" of having the devices in a real directory on a root filesystem, and `devfs`, the first virtual filesystem solution for `/dev`.

The problem was, the author of `devfs` had constructed a completely new naming scheme for various devices, and people felt fairly strongly about it: some wanted to migrate to the new scheme and abolish the old one, others didn't see the need for migration. Some distributions used the old static devices, others chose `devfs`.

At that point, there was a fixed number of pseudo-TTY devices created at installation time. (By the way, this is still possible, if the `CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS` option is set while compiling your kernel.)

Then, Unix98-style dynamically-allocated PTY devices were introduced. Implementing them on a static `/dev` directory required a virtual filesystem for `/dev/pts`, and this became known as the `devpts` filesystem. Also, having this as a separate filesystem would probably have made it possible to apply it on top of the dynamic `devfs` too without duplication of code.

The dynamically-allocated PTY devices quickly became the favored choice, because having `/dev` cluttered with hundreds of statically-allocated PTY devices, most of which might well never be used in the system's lifetime, was clearly nonsensical.

Then came Linux 2.6 and `udev` with it. It quickly obsoleted both the static `/dev` and `devfs` solutions. For backwards compatibility reasons, `devpts` filesystem still existed, but now the same functionality could be moved back to the main `/dev` filesystem, since it was now entirely RAM-based.

Today, for example, Debian 9 still mounts `devpts` filesystem to `/dev/pts` for legacy compatibility, but assigns `/dev/pts/ptmx` zero permissions by default - this is a sign that the `devpts` filesystem is probably being deprecated and will be removed at some future point.

```
# ls -l /dev/ptmx /dev/pts/ptmx
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty  5, 2 Nov 22 11:47 /dev/ptmx
c--------- 1 root root 5, 2 Nov 12 14:59 /dev/pts/ptmx
```

If some program still needs `/dev/pts/ptmx`, that can be allowed by adjusting the default permissions, but this lets people know which programs are still using the older deprecated device name.

Answer (score 0):

When a process opens /dev/ptmx (using [posix_openpt()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_openpt.3.html) ), it gets a file descriptor for a pseudoterminal master (PTM), and a pseudoterminal slave (PTS) device is created in the /dev/pts directory.

When the master is opened the slave is locked. You can obtain the name of the slave and set it's permissions etc. and then unlock the slave. This allows control of the slave before it is accessible.

The slave emulates a real text terminal device, the master provides the means by which a terminal emulator process controls the slave.

The slave is a virtual implementation of a physical terminal and the master is a virtual implementation of the human typing on that terminal; the computer treats characters sent to the slave the same as if a human had typed them on a real terminal (limited by the permission setup when the master was created).