# Some confused concept: ptmx and tty

Tags: tty

All the following commands run in my debian terminal.

```
ls /dev |grep ptmx
/dev/ptmx

ls  /dev/pts
0  1  ptmx
```

What is the difference between `/dev/ptmx`  and `/dev/pts/ptmx`?

```
ls  /dev/tty* |sort
/dev/tty
/dev/tty0
/dev/tty1
/dev/tty10
```

Is there a relation between /dev/tty  and /dev/tty0 (/dev/tty1....) ?
/dev/tty control all other  /dev/tty[number] ?

Comment: This is two questions in one, and the second has been covered already by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447197/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229530/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446166/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187319/ ,  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127259/ , and others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/dev/ptmx` is the standard one, `/dev/pts/ptmx` is added for software containers (Docker etc.) and other cases when you need multiple instances of the `devpts` filesystem.

### The nature of device nodes

You should realize that the "magic" of a device node is not in its name, but in the *major & minor device numbers* it's created to embody.

For example, if you have the appropriate privilege, you can use `mknod` to create a character device node with major 1 and minor 3 with any name, in any Unix-style filesystem, and - unless the filesystem has the `nodev` mount option - it will behave exactly like `/dev/null`, because for all intents and purposes, it **will be** another realization of `/dev/null`.

Likewise, both `/dev/pts/ptmx` and `/dev/ptmx` are character devices with major number 5 and minor number 2. So they will provide access to the exact same functionality within the kernel.

```
$ ls -l /dev/ptmx /dev/pts/ptmx
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty  5, 2 Jun 12 20:14 /dev/ptmx
c--------- 1 root root 5, 2 Jun 12 12:26 /dev/pts/ptmx
```

The type of the device node (character or block) and the major & minor device numbers together define which kernel device driver that device node interfaces with. The kernel doesn't care about names - it provides default names for `udev`, but you're free to completely redesign the device naming scheme if you feel like it. You can create device nodes outside `/dev`, if you need to.

In Debian 9, the `/dev/pts/ptmx` has permissions set to 000 by default, so it is not expected to be used. Likewise in RHEL 7.5.

[The comment in 4.17 kernel source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/devpts/inode.c?h=v4.17) says:

```
/*
 * ptmx is a new node in /dev/pts and will be unused in legacy (single-
 * instance) mode. To prevent surprises in user space, set permissions of
 * ptmx to 0. Use 'chmod' or remount with '-o ptmxmode' to set meaningful
 * permissions.
 */
```

"single-instance mode" refers to usage as a system conforming to UNIX98 and Single Unix Specification v1 standards. So it's pretty important backwards compatibility.

The multi-instance capability for `devpts` was developed for container support. This can be confirmed by reading the [old versions of `<Linux kernel source>/Documentation/filesystems/devpts.txt` from year 2009 or so](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/filesystems/devpts.txt?id=784c4d8b1b1e66f8c45e8b889613f4982f525b2b):

> To support containers, we now allow multiple instances of devpts
>   filesystem, such that indices of ptys allocated in one instance are
>   independent of indices allocated in other instances of devpts.
>
> To preserve backward compatibility, this support for multiple
>   instances is enabled only if:
>
> - CONFIG_DEVPTS_MULTIPLE_INSTANCES=y, and
> - '-o newinstance' mount option is specified while mounting devpts
>
> IOW, devpts now supports both single-instance and multi-instance
>   semantics.

When containers are in use, they will typically initialize an entirely new namespace for pseudo-TTYs, and may mount another instance of the `devpts` filesystem within the container (this could even be omitted if pseudo-TTY support within the container is not needed). The presence of a `ptmx` entry within the `devpts` filesystem may be useful in minimizing the work needed to initialize the in-container environment.

Comment: Actually that and your answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406240/5132 have this backwards. The ability to have multiple `devpts` filesystems in containers means that `/dev/pts/ptmx` is the primary interface and `/dev/ptmx` is a link/bind mount to it, as discussed at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=501718. More recent Kernel comments [and doco](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/eedf265aa003b4781de24cfed40a655a664457e6/Documentation/filesystems/devpts.txt) specifically call out single-instance mode as the old way, and retaining `/dev/ptmx` for "backwards compatibility".

Comment: Oops. That's what I get by not fact-checking hard enough. But note that the "new way" is for containers, and the "old way" is the standards-compliant traditional Unix-like system.

Comment: Again, no.  The POSIX standard only mandates a `posix_openpt()` function. It _does not_ mandate that it be implemented with a `/dev/ptmx` device, and indeed on several operating systems it is not.  The old way is just as much a Linuxism as the new way.  Moreover, the new way is not just for containers.  It is for everything, and it ensures that the multiplexor is always tied to the right filesystem.

Comment: Then please explain why both Debian and RHEL set `/dev/pts/ptmx` to permissions 000 to discourage its use, and clearly favor the use of `/dev/ptmx`?

Comment: Or rather, what's the source of your information?

Comment: Reading the `posix_openpt()` section of the POSIX standard, and using those other operating systems.  (-:  But really you need to be asking yourself where you got the misinformation that "Debian and RHEL" do this (it is not them, but the kernel) "to discourage its use" (which was not the original purpose, but rather to provide a backwards-compatible way of _introducing_ the new `/dev/pts/ptmx` node).

Comment: Which other operating systems? Sun/Oracle Solaris has `/dev/ptmx` but not `/dev/pts/ptmx`. HP-UX man pages from 2007 document `/dev/ptmx` but not `/dev/pts/ptmx`. AIX does slightly its own thing, and names the master device `/dev/ptc`. Based on that, it looks like `/dev/ptmx` is the established way to implement this SysV-style interface, and `/dev/pts/ptmx` is the anomalous version. So, history seems to be on the side of `/dev/ptmx`, and (unfortunately) that's a very powerful force. What other operating systems you're looking at? Are they perhaps all on the BSD side of Unix family tree?